# Html Css style rule

Tags: c#, css

I am trying to make a css rule for a list that contains string values.

I need something like this:

```
<style>
@string.Join(", ", Model.MyList.Select(x =>[val='{0}'])
{
    color: red;
}
</style>
```

I want my rule would be something like:

```
<style>
[val='value1'], [val='value2'], [val='value3']
{
  color: red
}
</style>
```

The problem is that the code is giving me syntax error and I am not sure what is the cause

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<style>
    @Html.Raw(string.Join(", ", Model.MyList.Select(x => $"[val='{x}']")))
    {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I tried your option but It says that I am missing a selector in the style rule. I am not sure that @Html.Raw works for Asp.Net-Core

Comment: I wrote this in Asp.Net Core razor page and worked fine. I can see Visual Studio giving the "Missing a selector in the style rule" warning but, it should run fine since the selector is being populated dynamically.

Comment: When I run the app It also gives me an error saying that the list is null, but I checked with the debug and the list is not null. Could it be a problem the fact that the list is being populated after submitting a form?

Comment: `gives me an error saying that the list is null` try to add additional code logic to check MyList object, for example `@Html.Raw(string.Join(", ", Model.MyList.Count() > 0 ? Model.MyList.Select(x => $"[val='{x}']") : new List<string> { "nm_selector" }))`.